# spark jupyter notebook does not show scala console output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

1) I am learning streaming and run into problems of nothing shown up (println via sendEVent)  on the console (scala). I further attempted to  inplant line of println("xyz") and found out that it only get printed if they are not embedded within the block of 'while' block... otherwise it wont get printed even placed before the while loop. I placed a few more lines of those println("xyz") and found out some might get blocked out... and only the last one get printed out.

Previously I also encounted twice with two different pieces of codes on Storm streaming that: nothing get printed out from Jupyter Notebook but perfectly ok on Scala Shell.

2) Also I wonder in those awaitTermination(),  such as:
messages.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination()  (I also get no output from console)

or those "infinitive loop" as shown bellowing codes:
var finished = false
while (!finished) {................. ..}

are they waiting for a hard break like halt or [CTR]C... or how to break them properly? so the next line get executed. I get so confused as the author writing the samples / tutorials explained nothing about this.

```
enter code here

import java.util._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.concurrent._

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs.ConnectionStringBuilder

// Event hub configurations
// Replace values below with yours        
val eventHubName = "<Event hub name>"
val eventHubNSConnStr = "<Event hub namespace connection string>"
val connStr = ConnectionStringBuilder (eventHubNSConnStr)
.setEventHubName(eventHubName).build 

import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs._
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)

def sendEvent(message: String) = {
  val messageData = EventData.create(message.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  eventHubClient.get().send(messageData)
  println("Sent event: " + message + "\n")
}


import twitter4j._
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
import twitter4j.Twitter
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder

// Twitter application configurations
// Replace values below with yours   
val twitterConsumerKey = "<CONSUMER KEY>"
val twitterConsumerSecret = "<CONSUMER SECRET>"
val twitterOauthAccessToken = "<ACCESS TOKEN>"
val twitterOauthTokenSecret = "<TOKEN SECRET>"

val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
cb.setDebugEnabled
(true).setOAuthConsumerKeywitterConsumerKey).setOAuthConsumerSecret
(twitterConsumerSecret).setOAuthAccessToken
(twitterOauthAccessToken).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twitterOauthTokenSecret)

val twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build())
val twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance()

//Getting tweets with keyword "Azure" and sending them to Event Hub realtime 

val query = new Query(" #Azure ")
query.setCount(100)
query.lang("en")
var finished = false
while (!finished) {
  val result = twitter.search(query)
  val statuses = result.getTweets()
  var lowestStatusId = Long.MaxValue
  for (status <- statuses.asScala) {
  if(!status.isRetweet()){
  sendEvent(status.getText())
}
  lowestStatusId = Math.min(status.getId(), lowestStatusId)
  Thread.sleep(2000)
}
query.setMaxId(lowestStatusId - 1)
}

// Closing connection to the Event Hub
eventHubClient.get().close()
```